# How to do sequentially and conditionally reactive programming?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I want to execute two or more operation as sequentially and conditionally.The operations should execute sequentially. The following example already can do this.

But I can not do that. According to the result of the first operation, I want to decide whether or not the second operation should work. According to the result of the first operation, I want to pass parameters to the second operation.

I know that it can work if codes write in subscribe event scope. But it must work sequentially and the first operation response will effect to second operation request. Same time another third operation can be added to the 'concat' response of  first and second operation with 'concat' operator. Same time, I want to use the same variable context. How can we do?

```
        var first: Observable<any> = this.http.get("https://testdb.firebaseio.com/.json").do((result1: any) => {
            //to do something with result1
            console.log("first operation");
        });

        var second: Observable<any> = this.http.get("https://testdb.firebaseio.com/.json").do((result2: any) => {
            ////to do something with result2
            console.log("second operation");
        });

        first.concat(second).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap), [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) or [`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) (or if you are using rxjs4: `flatMap`) - when in doubt: use [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap)

```
    const first$ = this.http.get("https://testdb.firebaseio.com/.json").do((result1: any) => {
        //to do something with result1
        console.log("first operation");
    });

    const second$ = this.http.get("https://testdb.firebaseio.com/.json").do((result2: any) => {
        ////to do something with result2
        console.log("second operation");
    });

    first$
        .switchMap(result1 => {
            if (resultIsOkay(result1)) {
                return second$;
            } else {
                return Observable.empty();
                // alternatively: return Observable.of(result1);
            }
        })
        .subscribe();
```